# how to show footnote which is inside \underline?

Tags: footnotes

What to do to make `\footnote` show up, when it is inside `\underline` ?

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\begin{document}
\underline{Case\footnote{$\lambda$ is real eigenvalue} $\lambda\neq0$}

Where is the footnote?

\end{document}
```

Compiling the above using `lualatex` produces no error, but the `footnote` do not show at bottom of page. TexLive 2017 on cygwin.

Comment: you can use `\footnotemark` where you want the mark and then `\footnotetext{...}` outside the underline (if you really have to underline)

Comment: For text-mode underlining, use either `\ul` from the `soul` package or `\uline` from the `ulem` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `soul` for underline (which comes with other advantages).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\ul{Case\footnote{$\lambda$ is real eigenvalue} $\lambda\neq0$}

The \texttt{soul} package has some nice features, e.g.\ it \ul{allows to
underline also over line and page breaks} which is something that unfortunately \underline{ordinary underline
does not}. And so on.

\end{document}
```